# java find price value in string

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to find price value in string(incoming sms message). I am using java regex:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+.\\d\\d");/`

But this expression find the date too. For example `12.12.2013` returns `12.12`.
If there some way to find only price value? Maybe not using regex, because string isn't long.

**EDITED**
Example of message:

Oplata tovariv: S1LV0GRU RYKAVUCHKA 510, UA 02.04.2013 21:12 kartka 1111111111 na sumu **24.72UAH**. Dostupnyi zalyshok 1351.58UAH.

Comment: What is your input sample?

Comment: @AchintyaJha, I was gonna ask the same thing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the general format of your prices is xxxx.xx, you can use:

```
"(?<!(?:\\d|\\.))\\d+\\.\\d{2}(?!\\.)"
```

At least it wouldn't match dates.
(Don't forget to escape the point so it's not a wildcard)

Comment: Did you test it? it return 2.20

Comment: Damn, I made a mistake while editing it, really sorry, editing again...

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" \\d+\\.\\d\\d ");
```

This will look for spaces before and after the price.

Comment: And would also match 2012.04.05 :)